# What is the best place to ask questions about deep learning, reinforcement learning, neural networks?

Tags: discussion

I started with AI at SO, and too with Quora, but both places seem to not really be used by people working in these areas. I am judging by traffic. Are there other places where people meet and discuss their stuff?

Comment: If you are looking for the best place to "discuss stuff", then Stack Exchange is probably not for you, it is for Q&A content only (unless you count the chat rooms). If you want the best Stack Exchange site for your purpose, then you should ask on Meta Stack Exchange, and you should give more details of the kinds of question you want to ask. Any of Cross Validated, Data Science, AI, Robotics, Signal Processing might be appropriate depending on your focus.

Answer (score 0):

- https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/